# validating user input using Try/Parse?

Tags: c#, tryparse

```
if (!char.TryParse(txtCustomerName.Text, out charCustomerName))  //try to read in Layers from TextBox
{
    MessageBox.Show("Customer Name must be entered.", "Invalid Customer Name");
    return;
}

if (!Decimal.TryParse(txtAmountOwed.Text, out decAmountOwed))  //try to read in Layers from TextBox
{
    MessageBox.Show("Amount Owed must be entered without dollar signs or commas.", "Invalid Amount Owed");
    return;
}

if (!int.TryParse(txtDaysOverdue.Text, out intDaysOverdue))  //try to read in Layers from TextBox
{
    MessageBox.Show("Days Overdue must be entered as a whole number.", "Invalid Days Overdue");
    return;
}
```

When I run the program, it tells me the customer name must be entered even though I entered it. How do I change that?

Comment: Just curious, why are you trying to use `char.TryParse`?  That will try to parse the String (text) into a `char` type, which is a single character.

Comment: You are trying to parse a single character out of a string of characters. Don't you really need just `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCustomerName.Text)`?

Comment: Andrei, IsNullOrWhiteSpace is better

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
if (!char.TryParse(txtCustomerName.Text, out charCustomerName))
```

with

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCustomerName.Text))
```

char represents ony one character

Comment: Use IsNullOrWhiteSpace

Comment: @L33TS - probably a space is a valid username in his case - he didn't define it in his question

Comment: Why is an empty string not valid then? He never specified empty strings weren't valid either, but generally white space or empty strings are never valid for names.

Comment: String.IsNullOrEmpty means: nothing was entered. i just want to say that the validation of the username is another issue

Comment: White-spaces are nothing either.`" ", "\t"` etc. are all white space characters which shouldn't be valid for a customer name (not a username like you specified.) On top of that `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` also checks for empty strings. It's generally safer to use. There was a reason `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` was introduced; simply because usually when you work with empty strings you don't work with white spaces either.